# Getting jQuery html to reappear

Tags: jquery, html, timer, count, warnings

Thanks for reading this in advance.

I am trying to get a message to appear that gives my users a warning. I have successfully done this, but when I repeat the action that my function uses, the message is not appearing again.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
//take 5 seconds off the timer
                var count = parseInt($('.timerCount').html());
                $('.timerCount').html(count - 5);
                $('.timerWarnings').html("5 seconds has been deducted from the timer");
                $('.timerWarnings').fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: where is the part where you show the message again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you fade out an element, it stays hidden until you tell it not to be. Do `.show().fadeOut()` to ensure the element starts off visible.

Comment: Wonderful! I tried .fadeIn() before but no use.. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should first make the message to reappear in case it was hidden during previous iteration:

```
var count = parseInt($('.timerCount').html());
$('.timerCount').html(count - 5);
$('.timerWarnings')
 .show()
 .html("5 seconds has been deducted from the timer")
 .fadeOut("slow");
```